# Some of my Hindi characters are not showing correctly in my CHtmlView (xml.xsl). Why?

Tags: html, xml, mfc, xslt-1.0, hindi

MFC
Dialog
VS2015

My application uses a **CHtmlView** browser. In this context is it a hidden browser that is purely used to fire the **print preview** mechanism. I have just started to add support for printing webpages with **Hindi** content.

When my application is displaying the **Print Preview** (via CHtmlView), sometimes the text is not showing correctly:

[image: CHtmlView]

The content being displayed is an image with text overlay. Simple stuff. The font is **Arial Unicode MS**. The data is **XML** using a **XSL** template.

If I open the same file directly in **Internet Explorer 11**:

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

As you can see, it has shown the same text correctly.

And if I right-click in IE11, and view source, and copy it into **Microsoft Expression Web 4**:

[image: MS Expression Web 4]

Again, it all looks good. So why is the **CHtmlView** print preview not displaying it correctly?

If you have any ideas as to why this may be happening I would like to know. The other 30 languages I support (including **Arabic** does not suffer this problem).

This is the **head** section of the HTML. And I confirm that the HTML file is **UTF-8** encoded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="hi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>
              Assignment Slips
            </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .containerPage {
    }
    .containerSlip{
        float:left;
        position: relative; 
        margin: 3mm;
    }
    .fieldName {
        position: absolute;
        left: 45px; top: 48px; width: 265px;
    }
    .fieldAssisant {
        position: absolute;
        left: 63px; top: 85px; width: 246px;
    }
    .fieldDate {
        position: absolute;
        left: 56px; top: 124px; width: 254px;
    }
    .fieldCounsel {
        position: absolute;
        left: 76px; top: 158px; width: 230px;
    }
    .fieldOther {
        position: absolute;
        left: 77px; top: 291px; width: 155px;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }
    .checkBibleReading {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px; top: 215px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkInitialCall {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px; top: 232px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkReturnVisit {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px; top: 248px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkBibleStudy {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px; top: 267px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkOther {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px; top: 285px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkMainHall {
        position: absolute;
        left: 176px; top: 215px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkAuxClass1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 176px; top: 232px; width: 15px;
    }
    .checkAuxClass2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 176px; top: 248px; width: 15px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

But please keep in mind that the content of the hidden CHtmlView (which fires the Print Preview) is the result of the XML/XSL translformation.

This is the **XSL** template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:attribute name="lang">
          <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <head>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Template/@Style"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </link>
          <title>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/ReportTitleWorksheets"/>-->
            Assignment Slips
          </title>
          <style type="text/css">
            @import url('<xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Template/@Style"/>');
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <xsl:for-each select="AssignmentSlips/Page">
            <div class="containerPage">
              <xsl:if test="@PageBreakBefore=1">
                <br style="page-break-before: always;"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:for-each select="StudentSlip">
                <div class="containerSlip">
                  <img alt="s89" width="323px" height="429px">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Template"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </img>
                  <div class="fieldName">
                    <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Student"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fieldAssisant">
                    <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Assistant"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fieldDate">
                    <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fieldCounsel">
                    <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="StudyPoint"/>
                  </div>

                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Assignment=1">
                      <div class="checkBibleReading">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Assignment=2">
                      <div class="checkInitialCall">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Assignment=3">
                      <div class="checkReturnVisit">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Assignment=4">
                      <div class="checkBibleStudy">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Assignment=5">
                      <div class="checkOther">✓</div>
                      <div class="fieldOther">
                        <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                          <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Other"/>
                      </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Location=1">
                      <div class="checkMainHall">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Location=2">
                      <div class="checkAuxClass1">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Location=3">
                      <div class="checkAuxClass2">✓</div>
                    </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </div>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I confirm that I keep getting this sporadic problem of some characters not showing right in my specific print preview.

Comment: You haven't shown the html `<head>` tag. Probably this is BOM related. Create a new file with notepad, save in "UTF-8" format. Change the extension to html and open directly with Internet Explorer to see if it works.

Comment: I have updated the question with the info you asked for, I confirm that the HTML I am using is UTF-8. So is the XSL file and the XML file. It just seems to be inside the CHtmlView print preview it does this.

Comment: I still don't have an issue to this problem. Maybe I will have to ask on the MSDN Social forums.

Comment: I don't see how this problem could be specific to `CHtmlView`. I was able to put to copy/paste hindi text and show in `CHtmlDialog`. If you can reproduce this problem in IE or IE/preview mode then you can ask a larger audience for help

Comment: All I know is, that invoking a Print Preview causes this issue via CHtmlView web browser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to provide a new answer for this issue.

What I had to do was get the `CHtmlView` to use the **latest** installed **Internet Explorer** browser. This can be achieved by inserting this `meta` data directly after the `<head>` tag, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

So the `<head>` element might look like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Styles here */
    </style>
    <title>Document Title</title>
</head>
```

Since my HTML document is created using a XSL transformation I was able to include the above meta. The only side effect of using the latest browser was that my page-breaks were no longer working. But I was able to change my HTML syntax to get them working again.

A simple code change to the HTML file will get it to use the latest installed browser. No more font corruption!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but my:

```
body
{
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

... top level CSS formatting was not being honoured.

I had to replicate the setting into each of my CSS classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
.containerPage {
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.containerSlip{
    float:left;
    position: relative; 
    margin: 3mm;
}
.fieldName {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45px; top: 46px; width: 265px;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
}
.fieldAssisant {
    position: absolute;
    left: 63px; top: 81px; width: 246px;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
}
.fieldDate {
    position: absolute;
    left: 56px; top: 122px; width: 254px;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
}
.fieldCounsel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 76px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 230px;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
}
.fieldOther {
    position: absolute;
    left: 77px; top: 289px; width: 155px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
}
.checkBibleReading {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px; top: 213px; width: 15px;
}
.checkInitialCall {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px; top: 232px; width: 15px;
}
.checkReturnVisit {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px; top: 248px; width: 15px;
}
.checkBibleStudy {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px; top: 267px; width: 15px;
}
.checkOther {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px; top: 285px; width: 15px;
}
.checkMainHall {
    position: absolute;
    left: 176px; top: 213px; width: 15px;
}
.checkAuxClass1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 176px; top: 232px; width: 15px;
}
.checkAuxClass2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 176px; top: 248px; width: 15px;
}
</style>
```

[image: Print Preview from CHtmlView]

Comment: I just want you all to know that this issue seems to have reared it's ugly head again. :(